# How to remove alu seat post from carbon frame?

Tags: maintenance, seatpost, carbon, aluminum

My aluminium seat post is seized into my carbon frame. To make matters worse the seat post is snapped at the seat post collar - nasty crash.

Anyone have a way to get it out? Or is it time for the dump?

Comment: You might try a trip to the plumbing department at your local bike shop (or *maybe* your local hardware store) and get an ["internal pipe wrench"](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/db9cb173-e166-41af-8162-7724d3858d83/svn/general-tools-wrenches-139-4-64_1000.jpg).  This is used for removing broken-off pipes from pipe fittings, and it will allow you to twist the broken-off stub.  It will not, however, allow you to tug on it very much, so it's far from a guaranteed solution.

Comment: If the seatpost snapped in the crash, then there's a great chance the frame has suffered some impact as well.  You or your insurer might want to consider getting the frame x-rayed to see if it needs replacement.

Comment: @Criggie I thought the same thing. If the impact was strong enough to snap the seatpost it was most likely strong enough to damage the frame in that region. And it is also most likely that the damage remains invisible until ...

Answer (score 3):

What you need is some way to grip or gain purchase on the post so you can apply a force to, then apply the usual methods to free the post from the frame.

Possible means of gripping the post I can think of:

- Old quill stem inserted into stem and tightened
- Star fangled nut inserted into seatpost, with a long bolt threaded into it.

[GCN has a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54WhdrLKKvY) showing how to use hot water to free up the post. It seems that a substantial amount of force is still needed to pull the post out though.

Comment: This guy used a slide hammer... Don't know  if the star nut idea  would survive but could be worth a try. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3ek2GeZzE0.